# Flutter: BloC: SubBloC doesn't change when reordering list

Tags: flutter, bloc

I seem to have a wrong thinking when using a listview with BloC.

I have a listview populated by a BloC (dataBloc) and this list is ordered by a ViewBloc.
When I tap on the item, a SubDataBloc is updated and the result displayed in the trailing of the list tile

dataBloc/viewBloc:

- ListTileA - SubdataBlocA
- ListTileB - SubDataBlocB
- ListTileC - SubDataBlocC

When I reorder the list - only the ListTiles are reordered, but not the SubdataBloc results
video:
https://gitlab.com/bridystone/bloc_test/-/blob/main/BloC-ListTile.mov

the whole example is here:
https://gitlab.com/bridystone/bloc_test

any idea, on how to make this happen?

ListView.builder

```dart
      body: BlocBuilder<ViewBloc, ViewState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ViewInitial) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (state is ViewReadyForUI) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.sortedData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => BlocProvider(
                create: (context) => SubDataBloc(),
                child: MyTile(
                  dataItem: state.sortedData[index],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          return Text('should not happen');
        },
      ),
```

ListTile:

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //BlocProvider.of<SubDataBloc>(context).add(SubDataRequest(dataItem.id));
    return BlocBuilder<SubDataBloc, SubDataState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ListTile(
          leading: Text(dataItem.id.toString()),
          title: Text(dataItem.text),
          trailing: (state is SubDataReceived)
              ? Text('items: ${state.subdata.length}')
              : (state is SubDataUpdating)
                  ? Text('${state.percent}')
                  : Text('initial'),
          onTap: () => BlocProvider.of<SubDataBloc>(context)
              .add(SubDataRequest(dataItem.id)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've received a comment from Github/Bloc_library, which brought me to a solution.
I've transferred the SubdataBloc to the dataModel of the MainBloc.
So for each data, a corresponding SubBloc is stored.

I've now added the subDataBloc to the DataModel

```
class BlocModel {
  final Model model;
  SubDataBloc subDataBloc;

  BlocModel(this.model, this.subDataBloc);
}
```

and added the BloC during generation to the Model

```
    var modelData = List<BlocModel>.generate(
        event.requestId,
        (index) => BlocModel(
            Model(Random().nextInt(event.requestId), "BLABLABLA $index"),
            SubDataBloc())); // <-- added here
```

then I could just add the subbloc to the BlocBuilder with the bloc attribute

```
    return BlocBuilder<SubDataBloc, SubDataState>(
      bloc: dataItem.subDataBloc,      //<-- using the data model-BloC
      builder: (context, state) {
        return ListTile(
            leading: Text(dataItem.model.id.toString()),
            title: Text(dataItem.model.text),
            trailing: (state is SubDataReceived)
                ? Text('items: ${state.subdata.length}')
                : (state is SubDataUpdating)
                    ? Text('${state.percent}')
                    : Text('initial'),
            onTap: () =>
                dataItem.subDataBloc.add(SubDataRequest(dataItem.model.id)));
      },
    );
```

And now it is working as [intended](https://gitlab.com/bridystone/bloc_test/-/blob/3913a76d04565c0b2a96bc382e33ece0a69d985e/BloC-working.mov).